# How to get reports value of cost related attributes in non micros format via. adwords API?

Tags: google-ads-api

How to get reports value of cost related attributes in non micros format via. adwords API.

Answer (score 0):

You can not, you just can get the units they give to you and change the units by yourself

Comment: 'returnMoneyInMicros' => TRUE

Comment: I think tha is deprecated if it is not i should remove my answer

Comment: It's not only deprecated, it's been completely removed since Adwords API version `v201406`: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/archived-release-notes#whats-new_5